# Concatenate 3 different datasets for plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently having problem understanding how concatenating three numpy matrices can cause data to be changed. The three numpy matrices contains data for  what should be shown in a spectogram.

static:
[image]
delta:
[image]
delta_delta:
[image]

but somehow when i concatenate them [static delta delta_delta] and make the same plot it looks like this:

[image]

why has the data set become corrupt in the last one?.. Here is how  i concatenate and make the plots.

```
import os
import sys
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
from PIL import Image
from python_speech_features import logfbank
from python_speech_features import delta
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import librosa


        y,sr = librosa.load(fp,sr=16000)  #fp being path to audio file

        static_data = logfbank(y,sr,nfilt=13,preemph=0)
        delta_data = delta(static_data,1)
        delta_delta_data = delta(static_data,2)

        output_hstacked = np.concatenate((static_data,delta_data,delta_delta_data),axis=0)
        print output_hstacked.shape
        Y =  np.array(range(0,output_hstacked.shape[1]))
        X =  np.array(range(0,output_hstacked.shape[0]))
        X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
        plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,output_hstacked.T,cmap=cm.jet)
        plt.xlabel('Frames(s)')
        plt.ylabel('Frequency(Hz)')
        plt.title('MFSS features of ' + filename)
        #plt.yscale('log')
        plt.colorbar()
        #plt.show()
        plt.savefig(spectogram_path_test+"/"+modified_name+"_stacked.png")
        plt.close()

        Y =  np.array(range(0,static_data.shape[1]))
        X =  np.array(range(0,static_data.shape[0]))
        X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
        plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,static_data.T,cmap=cm.jet)
        plt.xlabel('Frames(s)')
        plt.ylabel('Frequency(Hz)')
        plt.title('MFSS features of ' + filename)
        #plt.yscale('log')
        plt.colorbar()
        #plt.show()
        plt.savefig(spectogram_path_test+"/"+modified_name+"_static.png")
        plt.close()


        plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,delta_data.T,cmap=cm.jet)
        plt.xlabel('Frames(s)')
        plt.ylabel('Frequency(Hz)')
        plt.title('MFSS features of ' + filename)
        #plt.yscale('log')
        plt.colorbar()
        #plt.show()
        plt.savefig(spectogram_path_test+"/"+modified_name+"_delta.png")
        plt.close()


        plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,delta_delta_data.T,cmap=cm.jet)
        plt.xlabel('Frames(s)')
        plt.ylabel('Frequency(Hz)')
        plt.title('MFSS features of ' + filename)
        #plt.yscale('log')
        plt.colorbar()
        #plt.show()
        plt.savefig(spectogram_path_test+"/"+modified_name+"_delta_delta.png")
        plt.close()
```

audio file can be found [here](https://clyp.it/10npq2tb)

Comment: Could that be an autoscaling issue? Looks like it to me. Check the ranges of the individual arrays.

Comment: notice the colour green is 0 for the and delta_delta where as 0 is orange in the last one, so I think it does represent the same data, what makes you think the data is being "corrupt"?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen based on how it visually represented... the plot should show static - delta-delta_delta lying next to each other.  The last plot doesn't resemble any part of the prior plots

Comment: Ahh... Wait I see what you mean..!

Comment: look at the numeric values, most around 0 with some streaks around 2.4 and -2.4, on the concatinated plot most around 0 (orange) with streaks of 2.4(red) and -2.4 (yellow)

Comment: What the Matlab tag? Consider deleting it if your questions is only about Numpy / Matplotlib

Comment: Yeah... this could be a problem... I was supposed to do features extraction on these images using CNN... Could the "Non dynamic colorchange" affect the performance of an CNN? (I know this is out scope questionwise)